# Calculating math from preview to master

Tags: php, math

I have a drawing board called preview. Which is scaled down proportionately to a height of 413. When a user chooses a point within the height, that must triangulate into a master board which height is 560. How would I interprate the chosen point on the preview board into the master board maintaining the same position?

```
$preview_height = 413;
$master_height = 560;

$point_on_preview = 200;
        
$point_on_master = ?    ``
```

Comment: Your `point_on_preview` variable only keeps track of one number... does this mean that the board is just a straight line?

Answer (score 0):

Considering aspect ratio is fixed meaning you scale down both width and height by the same factor:

```
// get the scaling factor
$factor = $preview_height / $master_height;
$point_on_master = $point_on_preview / $factor;
```

you might wanna round(), ceil(), or floor() the result, if you need integers.
This is basic math, you should get to know if you want to improve your development skills :)